# How to no follow the paginated comments

Tags: comments, pagination

I am trying to find a way to add `rel="nofollow"` to my comments pagination links.
Can anyone provide me with a hook or way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two special filters for that:

```
add_filter( 'previous_comments_link_attributes', 'wpse_77217_comment_nofollow' );
add_filter( 'next_comments_link_attributes', 'wpse_77217_comment_nofollow' );

function wpse_77217_comment_nofollow()
{
    return ' rel="nofollow"';
}
```